# How to stop a setInterval nested in a function with a clearInterval outside this function?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm having a hard time figuring out how I could stop a Setinterval called in a nested function by using a clearInterval located outside this function.

The Setinterval is declared at the level 0 of the DOM (is it correct to say that?). It is nos nested in a function.

```
 function interval()
        {
           setInterval(function calcRealPos(){
               console.log("realPos="+realPos)
             realPos+=10;
              },500);
         }
```

The function interval() is then called in a function :

```
function move(distance)
{
   // Movement using translate
   if (distance==1933.67)
   {
        interval();
   }
 }
```

I want to clear the interval whenever somebody presses 'D'. The clear interval is in another function which is not nested in any other function either :

```
function releasebtn(event)
{

 var unpressBtn = event.keyCode;

 if(unpressBtn==68)
    {
       clearInterval(interval());

    }

 }


  document.addEventListener('keypress', pushbtn);
  document.addEventListener('keyup', releasebtn);
```

Thanks!

Comment: `var interval; function interval() { interval = setInterval(/* code */) }`

Answer (score 1):

[`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) accepts the ID of the `setInterval` interval. You need to store the interval ID in a variable, then pass it to `clearInterval` like this:

```
function calcRealPos() { console.log('foo'); }

// Set the interval and store its ID
intId = setInterval(calcRealPos, 500);

// Later, when you want to clear the interval, use this
clearInterval(intId);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to stop setInterval, you will need to assign a reference to it (a global variable in this case). This is to ensure that javascript knows which setInterval to stop/clear.

Your setInterval function can be easily re-written to show this

```
 function interval()
        {
           myinterval=setInterval(function calcRealPos(){
           console.log("realPos="+realPos)
           realPos+=10;
              },500);
         }
```

now in your releasebtn function, you can stop it like

```
function releasebtn(event)
{

 var unpressBtn = event.keyCode;

 if(unpressBtn==68)
    {
       clearInterval(myinterval);

    }

 }
```